# Excel: calculate which occurance of a weekday, within the month, from any given date e.g. fifth Friday

Tags: excel, date

I am not very good at Excel. In the NHS (UK) we often schedule activity by looking at the columns on a calendar (e.g. All day theatre list Mondays week 1,3,5). This means on the first Monday, third Monday and if present fifth Monday. Using a printed calendar you can see the columns, for example Mondays in Jan 2023 where there are five.

[image]

When planning, it would be great to have a formula that would accept a date, and return the ordinal of the weekday for that month e.g.

- Jan 02 2023 = 1
- Jan 28 2023 = 4
- Jan 29 2023 = 5
- Jan 30 2023 = 5

I have searched and found the WEEKNUM function, but this counts rows on the calendar not giving the result I need.

Any help gratefully received

Kind Regards Gavin Holt

Comment: `=INT((DAY(A1)-1)/7)+1`

Answer (score 0):

This should return those values:

```
=-INT(-(DAY(YourCellWithTheDate))/7)
```